# Why does the binding of a customable widget take all the focus even if we create multiple widget?

Tags: python, binding, kivy

I would like to create 2 labels where I can trigger an event an do an action with the name of the label shen I double click on.

[Solution I found and that I'm using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49766953/python-kivy-call-function-when-double-click-on-label)

Problem: When I double click anywhere, the last custom widget that I created/gave the binding is trigger. So it works outside of the widget range so it's not the desire feature.

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ClickableLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Label.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_double_press')
        if kwargs.get("on_double_press") is not None:
            self.bind(on_double_press=kwargs.get("on_double_press"))

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.is_double_tap:
            self.dispatch('on_double_press', touch)
            print(self.text)
            return True
        return Label.on_touch_down(self, touch)

    def on_double_press(self, *args):
        pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        boxlayout = BoxLayout()

        label = ClickableLabel(text='Hello world', on_double_press=self.callback)
        boxlayout.add_widget(label)
        label_2 = ClickableLabel(text="it's Boby", on_double_press=self.callback)
        boxlayout.add_widget(label_2)
        return boxlayout

    def callback(self, *args):
        print("double clicked", args[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

EDIT:
here is a working example with focusable layouts.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ClickableBoxLayout(ButtonBehavior, BoxLayout):
    pass

class Line(ClickableBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.idx = 0

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.idx += 1
            print(self.idx)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout()
        c_1 = Line()
        b.add_widget(c_1)
        c_2 = Line()
        b.add_widget(c_2)

        c_1.add_widget(Label(text="Hello"))
        c_2.add_widget(Label(text="World"))
        return b

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `collide_point()` to determine if the `touch` event occurred within your `ClickableLabel`.

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics).